# ModelViewViewModel tasks

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm a noob in mvvm and I am developing my app with this arq, but I don't know how to separate tasks for UI and ViewModel

for example, I have a QR reader with zxing

```
/**
 * Init scanner
 */
private fun initScanner () {
    scannerView = ZXingScannerView(requireContext())
    scannerView = object : ZXingScannerView(requireContext()) {
        override fun createViewFinderView(context: Context): IViewFinder {
            val customLayout = CodiCustomQRReader(context)
            customLayout.setSquareViewFinder(true)
            customLayout.setBorderColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.codi_mango, null))
            return customLayout
        }
    }
    scanner.addView(scannerView)
}
```

This function is called from onviewCreated in my UI

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    requestPermissions()
    initScanner()
}
```

this is ok? or I need to call these kind of functions from viewmodel?

same case with function requestPermissions().

PD: same case again with fragment management for example

```
/**
 * Shows result dialog fragment when QR is read
 */
override fun handleResult(res: Result?) {
    val fragmentTransaction = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    val prev = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("scanner")
    if (prev != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.remove(prev)
    }

    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("handler")
    val dialogFragment = CodiScannerHandler()
    dialogFragment.setStyle( STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.ScannerDialog )
    dialogFragment.show(fragmentTransaction, "handler")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing everything quite right you cant write all of this logic in viewmodel because of one simple reason they all are using context and if you dont want something in your view model its context. in future if you have some kind of logic which wont use context for example requesting some info from retrofit client or room or deciding what color text should be based on some boolean you can write them in view model.
I will highly recommend you to read this documentation : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel